# vuex getter triggers 'infinite update loop in a component render function'

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I get an “infinite update loop in a component render function” and it seems to be triggered by a vuex getter but I have seriously no idea why. Any hint would help me a lot

```
getPlanningsForPlanner: (state, getters, rootState, rootGetters) => () => {
            let people = getters['getPeopleOrderedBy']();
            return rootState.plannings.map((planning) => {

                if (planning.adhoc_text === null) {
                    planning.epic = rootGetters['moduleJIRA/getEpicByKey'](planning.epic_key);
                    if (typeof (planning.epic) !== 'undefined')
                        planning.project = rootGetters['moduleJIRA/getProjectByKey'](planning.epic.fields.project.key)
                } else {
                    planning.epic = {};
                    planning.project = {};
                }

                // parse dates
                planning.startDate = moment(planning.start_date);
                planning.endDate = moment(planning.end_date);

                // add people
                planning.people = people.find(elm => elm.id === planning.people_id);

                // calculation of hours
                planning.dailyHours = getters['daysToHours'](1, planning.load);
                planning.businessDays = planning.startDate.businessDiff(planning.endDate) + 1;
                planning.plannedHours = getters['daysToHours'](planning.businessDays, planning.load);

                if (!planning.pinned_end) {
                    let fixPlannedEpics = rootState.plannings.filter(_planning => _planning.epic_key === planning.epic_key && _planning.pinned_end);
                    let fixPlannedHours = fixPlannedEpics.reduce((sum, _planning) => sum + _planning.plannedHours, 0);
                    let openlyPlannedEpics = rootState.plannings.filter(_planning => _planning.epic_key === planning.epic_key && !_planning.pinned_end);
                    let hours = Math.max((planning.epic.budget - planning.epic.sumTimeSpent - fixPlannedHours) / openlyPlannedEpics.length, planning.dailyHours);
                    planning.endDate = moment(planning.startDate).businessAdd(Math.round(hours / planning.dailyHours));
                }

                // add indices in timeBeam
                let indices = getters['getIndices'](planning.startDate, planning.endDate);
                planning.startIndex = indices.start;
                planning.endIndex = indices.end;

                return planning
            });
        },
```

Comment: Did you debug it? You can stop execution and examine stack trace, there will be you solution. You call a plenty of different getters here, any of them can cause infinite loop

Comment: You mustn't modify any state inside a getter (I see `planning.epic = {}`, for example).

Comment: thx Alex. The problem was indeed in a getter. I frequently forget that Array.sort doesn't simply return the sorted array but also do an in-situ sorting of the original array.